# IIS 6.0 application pool stop issue

Tags: iis, iis-6, application-pools

In my IIS log, I found warning level event ID 1013, which says the stop time exceeds expected stop time for worker process of a specific web application.

My question is, how could I know or track from what reason IIS worker process stops? Does this warning level event ID means worker process application pool is stopped or not?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

You could use Microsoft [Debug Diagnostics](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1286) for IIS.

> Debug Diagnostics (DebugDiag) 1.1 is a
>   comprehensive tool designed to help
>   IIS administrators or developers
>   determine why a IIS worker process is
>   crashing, hanging, or memory leak. It
>   offers a simple User Interface to
>   build rules for capturing these common
>   problems with web applications and
>   also offers a built-in analysis
>   system.

There are three components:

- debugging service: collects all kinds of debug information
- debugger host: hosts the Windows Symbolic Debugger Engine (dbgeng.dll) to attach to processes and generate memory dumps.
- user interface: analyze memory dumps, automate the creation of control scripts and show the status of running processes, including services

Here some links to tutorials: [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;919789), [ASPAlliance](http://aspalliance.com/1350_Post_Production_Debugging_for_ASPNET_Applications__Part_1.4).

Comment: My application is for classic ASP (.Net 1.1), not ASP.Net. Looks like "Debug Diagnostics" tool only for ASP.Net? Please correct me if I am wrong.